# Keras SimpleRNN - Shape MFCC vectors

Tags: python-3.x, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently trying to implement a Recurrent Neural Network in Keras. The data consists of a collection of 45.000 whereby each entry is a collection (of variable length) of MFCC vectors with each 13 coefficients:

```
spoken = numpy.load('spoken.npy')
print(spoken[0]) # Gives:
example_row = [
[  
       5.67170000e-01  -1.79430000e-01  -7.27360000e+00  -9.59300000e-02
      -9.30140000e-02  -1.62960000e-01   4.11620000e-01   3.00590000e-01
       6.86360000e-02   1.07130000e+00   1.07090000e-01   5.00890000e-01
       7.51750000e-01],
       [.....]
]
print(spoken.shape) # Gives: (45000,0)
print(spoken[0].shape) # Gives (N, 13) --> N amount of MFCC vectors
```

I'm struggling to understand how I need to reshape this Numpy array in order to feed it to the SimpleRNN of Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model_spoken.add(SimpleRNN(units=10, activation='relu', input_shape=?))
.....
```

Therefore, my question is how do I need to reshape a collection of variable length MFCC vectors so that I can feed it to the SimpleRNN object of Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually quite simple since Keras has built in function for reformatting the array and padding zeros to get a static length:

```
spoken_train = pad_sequences(spoken_train, maxlen=100)
```

See [github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/40)